# Download Ubuntu rootfs

Tags: system-installation, filesystem, chroot, container

Similar to what is possible with [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/)

[image]

is there a place where I can download some kind of official "core" rootfs of Ubuntu, mainly for `chroot` purposes?

Answer (score 3):

## Ubuntu Base

> Ubuntu Base is a minimal rootfs for use in the creation of custom images for specific needs. Ubuntu Base strives to create a suitable minimal environment for use in Board Support Packages, constrained or integrated environments, as the basis for application demonstration images, or Linux containers such as LX
> C or Docker (For OCI/docker container images, see also the Ubuntu OCI project). It is available for the i386, amd64, armhf, arm64, powerpc and ppc64el architectures.

- [Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base)
- [Download](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/)

**Warning**: Ubuntu Base is intended for advanced users who want to put together custom images. It is **not** a complete "minimal" Ubuntu image. It's merely one building block. It lacks an installer. It lacks a kernel. It's not a complete flavor.  It IS a real Ubuntu filesystem used by real Ubuntu developers. It's one of their tools.

While some gurus here might be able to answer some questions about it, it's not a released, versioned flavor of Ubuntu so technical support here for it is arguably a grey zone. (That means we won't write a tutorial for beginners to use it. Beginners should not use it.)

Comment: Also, [Ubuntu core](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/) might be of interest to OP ... I think.